# Java reading integers and strings from text file and then using the integers and strings

Tags: java, string, integer

I am attempting to read in some data from a text file, this goes in the format:

```
String (Monday)
String (M141)
Integer (16)
Integer (6)
Double (10.5)
Double (10.5)
Integer (20)
Integer (20)
Integer (20)
Integer (30)
```

I have managed to read the file and tried to use nextLine to display these, this worked but after using next line to print out these values I need to manipulate the data I need to add up (30, 20, 20, 20, 10.5, 10.5) and times this by (16) to get a final value but I cannot figure out a way to do this,  I tried to use an array to store them then manipulate them but had no luck. There is more than one set of data with the same format but different integers. Please help me understand how to go about this, I've been trying for over a day. Here is my code so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("C:\\data.txt"));

        System.out.println(reader.nextLine());
        System.out.println(reader.nextLine());
        System.out.println(reader.nextInt());
        System.out.println(reader.nextInt());
        System.out.println(reader.nextDouble());
        System.out.println(reader.nextDouble());
        System.out.println(reader.nextInt());
        System.out.println(reader.nextInt());
        System.out.println(reader.nextInt());
        System.out.println(reader.nextInt());

    }
}
```

EDIT:
I need to add up the (10.5) (10.5) (20) (20) (20) (30) and times it by 16.

Comment: So java has this weird thing where reader.nexInt() won't pick up the new line character at the end of the string. Just a side note if you do any more scanning after that. just grab all the ints as doubles and add them all up that should work fine. you could use an array or array list if you need to use the data later. If we got a sample piece of your data it would also help a lot.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want to accomplish.  In what format do you want the extracted data?  Are these values the attributes of some object?  As it seems to me, you'll have to parse the type information first, and then switch over the possible types to parse the parenthesized value correctly.  Is this what you are having trouble with?

Comment: I'm trying to read the data in from the file which I have done and print this. I need to add up the values that are in the file and ignore some parts of the file. Here is my data: 

Monday
M141
16
6
10.5
10.5
20
20
20
30


This data is being read, 16 is the number of hours the person works for. The 30, 20, 20, 20, 10.5 and 10.5 need to be added up and multiplied by 16

Comment: so that is one line of a file or is it 10 lines?

Comment: What are the rules by which you have to decide what to ignore, what to add and what to multiply?

Comment: The more specific information you can give to your problem the more we can help with your specific issue. Can you tell us the format of the text file and the end goal? EDIT just saw your edit.

Comment: So Day, identifier or something like that, rate, amount of days worked, hours worked per day... do you know how many lines or entries are in the file?

Comment: Here is the whole text file:

Monday < Don't need to do anything with this except print > 
M141 < Just a reference number, unneeded >
16 < Hours worked - need to use this >
6 < Number of staff in the team, don't need this>
10.5 <First persons pay (1)>
10.5 <Second>
20 <Third>
20 <Fourth>
20 <Fifth>
30 <Sixth>

Here is my data, all of the sections follow the same format. I need to add up the pay for Monday and multiply by 16, then loop this for the following days (Tuesday, Wed, Thurs and Friday)

Comment: Is my answer what you're looking for or are you looking for something different?

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble getting the numbers themselves look up Java Substring. It's very helpful. And also search Java IndexOf. These two methods will help you a lot. 
For example 
String a = "Bob(10)";
String x = a.substring(a.indexof("("),a.indexOf(")"));

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if the file is written in lines try

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("C:\\data.txt"));

String monday = reader.nextLine();
// splits up the string into pieces, seperated at the space
String[] parts = monday.split(" ");
String day = parts[0];

// you may have to use Integer.parseInt() here I don't remember
int hourMutiplier = parts[2];
int people = parts[3];
double wages = 0;
for( int i = 4; i < people + 3; i++){
  wages += parts[i];  
}
double finalWages = wages * hourmutiplier;
...
```

or something like that, syntax might be a little off.